# Download the files that are bigger than a certain size

Tags: bash, perl, shell, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have `Files.txt`, which consists of a list of URLs of Excel files:

```
http://www.bcheadset.ca/applicant.xlsx
http://www.bcheadset.ca/fte.xlsx
http://www.iutox.org/TRTF_Matrix2012_Oct.xlsx
http://www.journalprices.com/2013_FinalSummaryForWeb.xlsx
http://www.camts.org/7__2013_Aircraft_Checklist.xlsx
http://www.nanotr11.org/poster_program.xlsx
http://www.vliruos.be/media/6352100/nss2015_annex_3_budget.xlsx
...
```

What I want to do is to download (by wget) the files that are bigger than `10Mo`.

To verify if a file is bigger than `10Mo` before dowloading it, we could use `curl --head`. For instance, `curl --head http://www.bcheadset.ca/fte.xlsx` returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3158847
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 22:16:45 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "ffb49fecb9c8d01:c05"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 15:14:27 GMT
```

And from `Content-Length`, we can verify that it is bigger than `10Mo`.

My question is how to automate this by a piece of `Bash` or `Perl`. Especially I don't know how to extract the `Content-Length` and does a comparison...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LWP` and `perl` and send a `HEAD` request, fetching response headers. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $request = HTTP::Request -> new ( HEAD => 'http://www.google.com' ); 
my $agent = LWP::UserAgent -> new;
my $response = $agent -> request ( $request );
print $response -> header ( 'Content-Length');
```

And then use LWP to do a `GET` instead of a `HEAD` you want that file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to adapt to various HTTP forms and their content some type of pattern matching may be prudent. Here is a rough example of how to use glob matching in shell to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/sh


BUFFER=$(curl --head http://www.bcheadset.ca/fte.xlsx )

HOLD=""

TAKENEXT=0


for i in $BUFFER
do case "$i" in
       Content-Length:)
       TAKENEXT=1
       ;;
    *) if [ "$TAKENEXT" -eq 1 ]
       then HOLD="$i"
            break
       fi
       ;;
    esac
done

printf "SIZE was:  %s\n" "$HOLD"
```

Here is a simpler method using `grep`:

```
SIZE=$(curl --head http://www.bcheadset.ca/fte.xlsx | grep 'Content-Length:' | awk '{print $2}')

printf "%s\n" "$SIZE"
```

.

Comment: This is broken in at least two ways: `for i in $BUFFER` is subject to pathname expansion, and `Content-Lenght:` may appear anywhere in the header (as a field of another key)...

Comment: Also: `grep | awk` is usually a bad idea: `awk '/^Content-Length:/{print $2;exit;}'` would be a better replacement. By the way, the space after the colon is optional, so `$2` might or might not work...